# Update tags to full title

Tags: bug, status-completed

Some tags use a shortened version of a movie's name because of the tag length limit. But this limit has been increased, and I've come across some tags that can now use the full name.

[once-upon-a-time-in-west](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/once-upon-a-time-in-west) to [once-upon-a-time-in-the-west](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/once-upon-a-time-in-the-west)

[train-your-dragon-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/train-your-dragon-2) to [how-to-train-your-dragon-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to-train-your-dragon-2)

[the-curse-of-were-rabbit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-curse-of-were-rabbit) to [the-curse-of-the-were-rabbit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-curse-of-the-were-rabbit)

[tale-of-princess-kaguya](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tale-of-princess-kaguya) to [the-tale-of-the-princess-kaguya](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-tale-of-the-princess-kaguya)

[texas-chainsaw-2003](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texas-chainsaw-2003) to [the-texas-chainsaw-massacre-2003](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-texas-chainsaw-massacre-2003)

[girl-leapt-through-time](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/girl-leapt-through-time) to [the-girl-who-leapt-through-time](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-girl-who-leapt-through-time)

[greatest-game-ever-played](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greatest-game-ever-played) to [the-greatest-game-ever-played](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-greatest-game-ever-played)

[crouching-tiger](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crouching-tiger) to [crouching-tiger-hidden-dragon](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crouching-tiger-hidden-dragon)

[down-out-in-beverly-hills](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/down-out-in-beverly-hills) to [down-and-out-in-beverly-hills](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/down-and-out-in-beverly-hills)

[dont-be-afraid-of-dark](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dont-be-afraid-of-dark) to [dont-be-afraid-of-the-dark](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dont-be-afraid-of-the-dark) (might also need a year includes, 1973 or 2010)

[fantastic-world-of-dc-c](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-world-of-dc-c) to [the-fantastic-world-of-dc-collins](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-fantastic-world-of-dc-collins)

[2010-year-we-make-contact](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010-year-we-make-contact) to [2010-the-year-we-make-contact](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010-the-year-we-make-contact)

[extremely-loud-incredibly-close](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extremely-loud-incredibly-close) to [extremely-loud-and-incredibly-close](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extremely-loud-and-incredibly-close)

[a-million-ways-to-die](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-million-ways-to-die) to [a-million-ways-to-die-in-the-west](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-million-ways-to-die-in-the-west)

[perks-of-being-wallflower](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perks-of-being-wallflower) to [the-perks-of-being-a-wallflower](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-perks-of-being-a-wallflower)

[planes-trains-automobiles](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planes-trains-automobiles) to [planes-trains-and-automobiles](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planes-trains-and-automobiles)

[the-postman-always-rings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-postman-always-rings) to [the-postman-always-rings-twice](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-postman-always-rings-twice)

I found these by looking through the lesser used tags, but I only got through a small part of all tags, so I might be back with more.